# How Calculate Average Daily Variation in R?

Tags: r, max, min, calculated-columns, difference

I have a dataframe

```
# Create a, b, c, d variables
a <- c("06-25-20 08:00:00 AM","06-25-20 08:15:00 AM",
       "06-25-20 08:30:00 AM","06-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM", "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM", "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "09-25-20 08:45:00 AM","09-25-20 08:45:00 AM")
b <- c(4,5,8, "N/A", 4,5,"N/A",7,7,6)
c <- c(6,10,8, "N/A", 8,5,"N/A",8,7,2)
d <- c("N,A",10.5,8, "N/A", 8,5,"N/A",8,7,2)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
df$a = as.POSIXlt(df$a, format="%m-%d-%y%H:%M:%S", tz = 'EST')
df$b = as.numeric(b)
df$c = as.numeric(c)
df$d = as.numeric(d)
```

I am trying to calculate the difference between minimum and maximum values for each day, and then average all the differences for each column to get 1 value. I am hoping for an output that looks like so

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3   4.3   3.5
```

Comment: any news/update regarding your problem/the errors you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  group_by(date = as_date(a)) %>%
  summarize(across(c(b, c, d), ~((max(., na.rm = TRUE) - min(., na.rm = TRUE))))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarize(across(-date, ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
      b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.5     3  2.62
```

Note that this gives a different result than your output. Please explain how you get to your values.

E.g. column b, the max/min diffs are 4, 1, 0, 1, which averages to 1.5, not 3.

Comment: I might have just calculated them wrong

Comment: Ok, if the calculation from my solution aligns with what you expect, please consider accepting the answer, so that others can benefit  from it.

Comment: this gave me back a bunch of ```inf``` for all the columns. And I don't see anywhere in the code that summarizes the daily variation?

Comment: Well, the code does what you asked for. If it doesn‘t run with your data, then please update your question with a better example of your data.

Comment: In single steps the code does the following: it first groups by date and then calculates the difference between min and max for each day. We then ungroup the data and calculate the mean/average of that difference across all days, separately for each column.